# Wildcards in T-SQL LIKE vs. ASP.net parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my SQL statement I use wildcards. But when I try to select something, it never select something. While when I execute the query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Click handler

```
protected void btnTitelAuteur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cvalTitelAuteur.Enabled = true;
    cvalTitelAuteur.Validate();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        objdsSelectedBooks.SelectMethod = "getBooksByTitleAuthor";
        objdsSelectedBooks.SelectParameters.Clear();
        objdsSelectedBooks.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("title", DbType.String));
        objdsSelectedBooks.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("author", DbType.String));
        objdsSelectedBooks.Select();
        gvSelectedBooks.DataBind();

        pnlZoeken.Visible = false;
        pnlKiezen.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

In my Data Access Layer

```
public static DataTable getBooksByTitleAuthor(string title, string author)
{

    string sql = "SELECT 'AUTHOR' = tblAuthors.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + tblAuthors.LASTNAME, tblBooks.*, tblGenres.GENRE "
                + "FROM tblAuthors INNER JOIN tblBooks ON tblAuthors.AUTHOR_ID = tblBooks.AUTHOR_ID INNER JOIN tblGenres ON tblBooks.GENRE_ID = tblGenres.GENRE_ID "
                +"WHERE (tblBooks.TITLE LIKE '%@title%');";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, GetConnectionString());
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@title"].Value = title;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Books");

    return ds.Tables["Books"];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
string sql = "SELECT 'AUTHOR' = tblAuthors.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + tblAuthors.LASTNAME, tblBooks.*, tblGenres.GENRE "
           + "FROM tblAuthors INNER JOIN tblBooks ON tblAuthors.AUTHOR_ID = tblBooks.AUTHOR_ID INNER JOIN tblGenres ON tblBooks.GENRE_ID = tblGenres.GENRE_ID "
           +"WHERE (tblBooks.TITLE LIKE @title);";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, GetConnectionString());
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.Text);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@title"].Value = "%" + title + "%";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't include your query parameter inside a string literal.  Do it like this instead:

> WHERE (tblBooks.TITLE LIKE '%' + @title + '%');

Also, whenever you have a leading wildcard you should look into a full text index instead.  Your query as written is doomed to be much slower than it could be, because you can't use index when you have a leading wild card.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the were clause to your code. But now I have the following: The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator.

I guess because there aren't quotation marks around the @title. But when I do put quotationmarks around it, it still doesn't work.

Vincent

Comment: @Vin Ah, your problem is the text data type.  The text data type is exclusively for large data fields that would otherwise cause problems with sql server's 8192 bytes per row limit.  You need to use an nvarchar field for that column instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from John Allers is correct. As an aside, you should wrap the SqlDataAdapter in a `using` block:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, GetConnectionString()))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@title"].Value = title;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Books");

    return ds.Tables["Books"];
}
```