# Parameterized string and wildcards in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to build a MySQL query for a database search operation, where a user can specify a text string to match against a particular column. I figured that using the LIKE operator and surrounding the user input with % signs, to act as wildcards, would be best practice. I want the wildcards to be there on both the start and end so the user does not have to enter the whole string. Furthermore, I'd like to parameterize the query to avoid injection and whatnot. This leaves me with a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `sometable`
WHERE `name` LIKE ?
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 1,10
```

(Note that the `name` column is a VARCHAR(50) with collation utf8_general_ci.)

The parameter from the WHERE clause is added like so:

```
Using cmd As New OdbcCommand()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", "%" & strUserInput & "%")
    ...
```

However, what I now ended up with appears to be MySQL actually matching the `name` column against the concatenated string, treating the %'s as literals and not as wildcards as I had intended.
I also tried `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`, but this doesn't work either.

How would I glue a wildcard character to the start and end of a parameterized string? Or is there a much better way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try putting the % around the parameter INSIDE the procedure you're calling?  it avoids someone calling the procedure without the %'s on accident and its less data over the network. and it should work... the driver may be misshandling the %

Comment: @xQbert Do you mean `LIKE '%' + ? + '%'`? That just throws a syntax error.

Comment: `CONCAT('%', ?, '%');`

Comment: Did you check these links ? 

 

[sql-like-statement-not-return-a-wildcard-output-asp-net-c-sharp][1]

[wildcards-in-t-sql-like-vs-asp-net-parameters][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124257/sql-like-statement-not-return-a-wildcard-output-asp-net-c-sharp
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889100/wildcards-in-t-sql-like-vs-asp-net-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I oversaw something really stupid. The `LIMIT` clause was the problem - the database I was testing with was supposed to return only one or two rows per query, but because I specified 1,10 it skips the first result. I did not know LIMIT is zero-based. Oops.

Learning oppurtunity, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your SqlParameter name is `@name` not `name` : `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", string.Format("%{0}%", strUserInput);`

And your sql should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `sometable`
WHERE `name` LIKE @name
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 1,10
```